# What is the PowerShell Verb-Noun definition for the mkdir alias?

Tags: powershell

In Windows PowerShell, the alias `md` relates to the definition `mkdir`, which also seems to be an alias (i.e. not a Verb-Noun definition.) as this command indicates:

```
: get-item -path alias:* | where-object {$_.Definition -eq "mkdir"}

CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Alias           md -> mkdir
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PowerShell's [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet allows you to reflect on command names:

```
PS> Get-Command md

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                 
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                 
Alias           md -> mkdir
```

This tells you that `md` is an *alias* and that it resolved to a command named `mkdir`.

```
PS> Get-Command mkdir

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                 
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                 
Function        mkdir
```

This tells you that `mkdir` is a *function*.

To see that function's *definition* (function body), access the `.Definition` property on the object returned by `Get-Command`:

```
(Get-Command mkdir).Definition # outputs the function's body
```

The output of the above will tell you that `mkdir` is a [proxy function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/01/04/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/) for `New-Item -ItemType Directory`.
In other words: it provides a file-system-specific shortcut for creating directories to the more generic [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) cmdlet - see [`Get-Help about_Providers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) to learn about PowerShell's generalization of the concept of drives.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `md` is an alias for `mkdir`. However, the `mkdir` command is not an alias but is actually a PowerShell function similar to this:

```
Function mkdir($folder)
{
    New-Item $folder -ItemType "directory"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`mkdir` is a built-in function that works as a shortcut for `New-Item` with `-ItemType "Directory"` hard-coded. It's part of the "make life easier"-package MS provided to make the transition from cmd/bash and unix's bash easier, just like the `dir`, `type` ++ aliases (cmd-commands) and `ls`, `cat` ++ (unix bash-commands)

You can check out what it does using `Get-Command`:

```
(Get-Command mkdir)

CommandType Name  Version Source
----------- ----  ------- ------
Function    mkdir


(Get-Command mkdir).ScriptBlock
#Returns the functions script-block, listing parameters ++
#...
$wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('New-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
$scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd -Type Directory @PSBoundParameters }
```